# retrieve txt content of as many file types as possible

Tags: delphi, indexing, dms

I maintain a client server DMS written in Delphi/Sql Server.

I would like to allow the users to search a string inside all the documents stored in the db. (files are stored as blob, they are stored as zipped files to save space).

My idea is to index them on "checkin", so as i store a nwe file I extract all the text information in it and put it in a new DB field. So somehow my files table will be:

```
ID_FILE integer
ZIPPED_FILE blob
TEXT_CONTENT text field (nvarchar in sql server)
```

I would like to support "indexing" of at least most common text-like files, such as:pdf, txt, rtf, doc, docx,pdf, may be adding xls and xlsx, ppt, pptx.

For MS Office files I can use ActiveX since I alerady do it in my application, for txt files i can simply read the file, but for pdf and odt?

Could you suggest the best techinque or even a 3rd party component (not free too) that parses with "no fear" all file types?

Thanks

Comment: Ideally avoiding activex would be a dream, since indexing is done on the client and i don't want to force users to install office to make this feature work, this is why i was asking for suggestions of 3rd party not poor component (btw i need a "reader" component)

Comment: Although it's tricky (you don't get the text as you would expect it) Gnostice PDFtoolkit 4.0 VCL Can do the PDF stuff for you, or it did for me using files.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, could you please explain me more about "you don't get the text as you would expect it" (just a simple idea, not a techinal reply please)?

Comment: I checked and there is a method to extract text to a stringlist, this could be nice. But still it seems there is not a general component but i must use differnet techniques for every file type...

Answer (score 3):

searching documents this way would leed to a very slow and inconvenient to use, I'd advice you produce two additional tables instead of TEXT_CONTENT field.

When you parse the text, you should extract valuable words and try to standardise them so that you 
- get rid of lower/upper case problems
- get rid of characters that might be used interchangeably.
   i.e. in Turkish we have ç character that might be entered as c.
- get rid of verbs that are common in the language you are dealing with. 
   i.e. "Thing I am looking for", "Thing" "Looking" might be in your interest
- get rid of whatever problem use face.

Each word, that has already an entry in the table should re-use the ID already given in the string_search table.

the records may look like this. 
**original_file_table** 
  zip_id number
  zip_file blob

**string_search**
  str_id number
  standardized_word text (or any string type with an appropriate secondary index)

**file_string_reference**
  zip_id number 
  str_id number

I hope that I could give you the idea what I am thinking of.

Comment: I thanks you for the suggestion, this is more about application design than how to solve my problem (=having a unique component not written by me that can extract text from all main "text files").

Comment: i awarded the bounty to you even if my problem is not totally solved, since I used 250 points i'd better give them to you than have them losed.

Answer (score 2):

Your major problem is zipping your files before putting them as a blob in your database which makes them unsearchable by the database itself.  I would suggest the following.

> Don't zip files you put in the database.  Disk space is cheap.

You can write a query like this as long as you save the files in a text field.

```
Select * from MyFileTable Where MyFileData like '%Thing I am looking for%'
```

This is slow but it will work.  This will work because the text in most of those file types is in plain text not binary (though some of the newer file types are now binary)

The other alternative is to use an indexing engine such as Apache Lucene or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) which will as you put it

> parses with "no fear" all file types?

Comment: Many databases have an option to use compression on blob fields anyway, so you really shouldn't have to give up anything.

Comment: The NoSQL db are a good side solution compared to conventionnal db, especially for full text search. Apache Solr, Elastic Search (both made on Lucene) are good solution (but needs a lot of reading / testing). So +1 to Toby. Use a SQL server if you need table & relations between them, and index in Solr / Elastic Search your documents contents.

Comment: @GregM. I agree. But SQL Server is a constraint I cannot get rid of. So I am in the "tricks domain" now.I often foudn solution to problems by abusing some feature (Windwos security, SQL Server architecture), at last what is more of concern is to find a solution, even if non hortodox.

Comment: @Toby "No fear" is a kind of joke to say "with no problems or billions of exceptions", like "this pdf file is encoded in an unknown format"...

Comment: @user193655 : As I said in the end, keep you db and add Solr/ES. It's not as easy as writing it, but i really think it's worth the time you'll spend.